# Python: Open Excel Workbook If it Exists or Create it

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd, xlsxwriter, xlwt

I am trying to get a good method to see if an Excel spreadsheet exists, if it does use that, if not create a new excel file.  See code snippet below.  The weird thing is every time I run it, it crashed on first attempt.  If I run it again, it cruises through.  Any ideas why?  I am thinking it has something to do with xlrd vs. xlwt, but haven't found a solution yet.  All modules are up-to-date.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt
import os.path

fname=r'testmonthlyz.xlsm'
fname2=r'testmonthlyoutput2.xlsx'
#workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fname2)    
if os.path.isfile(fname2):
    print('old file')
    book=open_workbook(fname2)
else:
    print('new file')
    book=xlwt.Workbook(fname2)
    ws = book.add_sheet('Tested')
sheet_names=book.sheet_names()
```

Comment: What does `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fname2)` do?

Comment: It's for use in another part of the program.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the reason that is crashed is since when you are in the `else` section, you have the line `book=xlwt.Workbook(fname2)` which means the book type is `Workbook` which has no attribute called `sheet_names()`.
When you are using `book = open_workbook(fname2)` inside the `if`, book type is `Book` which does have `sheet_names()` attribute.
my solution to this, even though is's not the best way, but I think it will solve the issue you are dealing with..
change the following lines

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt
import os.path

fname=r'testmonthlyz.xlsm'
fname2=r'testmonthlyoutput2.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fname2)    
if os.path.isfile(fname2):
    print('old file')
    book=open_workbook(fname2)
else:
    print('new file')
    workbook2=xlwt.Workbook(fname2)
    ws = workbook2.add_sheet('Tested')
    workbook2.save(fname2)
    book = open_workbook(fname2)

sheet_names=book.sheet_names()
```

Comment: I'll give it a go.  Thanks for your time on this.  I'll let you know results!

Comment: Thanks.  Worked perfectly.